# Should I do yoga if I have flu symptoms?

Tags: health, yoga, safety

This morning I started to have flu symptoms, soar throat, sneezing, etc.

Should I stay home or the yoga class might improve the symptoms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're contagious or think you might be, why not just attempt the yoga at your house, and skip the class, and skip possible infection of others....

Also, I'm no doctor, but for sore throats, apple cider vinegar + water + honey = quick fix for sure.

Just fast, allow your body to focus on rebuilding your immune system. Do some stretches and yoga, relax, get some herbal tea or something, and drink plenty of water.

Hope you feel better!